# Get number of days between two dates using alternate day as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel userform that contains four text boxes: `start date`, `end date`, `Alternate Day number` & `result`.

A user enters a starting and ending date. For example `Start Date: 01/oct/2020` and `End Date: 04/jan/2021`.

In the `Alternate Day number` text box, the user enters an alternate day number, say `4`. This represents that an action begins on every `4th` day.

How could I code it so that VBA can work out the total number of alternate days between the two dates?

Answer (score 2):

You could even do this within Excel without VBA if you want to take that route. You could simply use the formula

```
= (end_date - start_date)/alternate_day_number
```

You could of course program the same formula in VBA as well.

Comment: worth to mention that this can come up with a result like 5.3 days. If only full days is needed you need to get the integer of it: `INT((end_date - start_date)/alternate_day_number)`. Also depending on if `end_date` and/or `start_date` are alternate dates or not you might need to add/subtract `1` from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your question is not clear to give only one answer.
Let's assume the following 2 dates:

[image]

You can get the total number as *The Guru* answered as

```
=(end_date - start_date)/alternate_day_number
```

this might come up with something like 3.5 if you only want full days as total number you need to take the integer

```
=INT(end_date - start_date)/alternate_day_number)
```

So for this example above the result is `3` but as you can see in the colored numbers depending wether you consider both `start_date` and `end_date` to be in the total number you need to add `+1` to the result (to make it all 4 dates).